# MongoDB: using $where in find() throws error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, where-clause

Surprised this hasn't been asked yet (well I can't find it), but lets say I am using the query:

```
db.find('this.CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber.indexOf("value") !== -1')
```

3/4s of my data has CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber as a string, but some of them have it as null, resulting in this error:

```
error: {
    "$err" : "TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of null near 'value\") !== -1' ",
    "code" : 16722
}
```

1. I must use a "javascript function" as a query
2. I have no control over the data

My question is, is it possible to pass some sort of "throwIsFalse" flag which means that whenever that function throws an error, the row is not matched?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a `$where` query for that as you can do it more efficiently (and without the problem you're hitting) as:

```
db.find({CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber: "value"})
```

But if you need to use a `$where` query for some reason, you would just need to check that `CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber` actually exists before calling `indexOf` on it:

```
db.find('this.CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber && this.CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber.indexOf("value") !== -1')
```

Comment: You're 100% right about efficiency, but my issue is that the queries are transpiled from oData, so I have no easy way to make them objects

Comment: @RoderickObrist Glad it helped. But keep in mind that no production system should be based on using `$where` queries for everything as the performance will be terrible at any kind of scale.